# Disable decimals in a input field

Tags: javascript, input, field

So, what I'm currently looking at is a code like this:

```html
<input class="quantity" type="text" value="1">
```

I want to remove/not allow decimals or in a way use math.floor as the user puts in a value such as 3.4 and the code will then change the input to 3.

Allow these numbers 0-9
Disallow .x

Comment: what have you tried so far? This isn't a free coding service. Find out how to read what's in the field, and look up the documentation for rounding numbers in Javascript. Both things are well-explained online already.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways you can achieve this is using [`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) like:

```html
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" 
    onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" 
    title="Numbers only" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var num = 3.3;
var n = num.toFixed(0)
```

if the value is 3.5 u will get 4. if it's below 3.5 u will get 3.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The Math.round () function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.Example with 2 decimals:

```
function round(num) {
//for example num=20.47
number = Math.round(num);
// Return the value 20
console.log(number); 
}
```